# /.zshrc:export:97: not valid in this context -w: not sure what this means?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

when I open up my terminal in Mac OS, the terminal prints at the top

```
   /.zshrc:export:97: not valid in this context -w
```

I modified a line in my /.zshrc file by following strict instructions online and using nano. I think I may have accidentally messed something up.

I opened the file on sublime, and the relevant lines are

```
 96 export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
 97 export EDITOR='subl' -w
 98 export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
 99 export EDITOR='subl' -w
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: if `-w` is a flag to `subl` it probably should instead be `export EDITOR='subl -w'` though some things may not like a space when they go to exec that program

Comment: do you know why there is a copy of lines 96/97 (and if 98/99 are necessary?

Answer (score 2):

A call to `export` may look like this:

```
export variable=value other_variable=its_value third_variable
```

This exports three variables and sets the values of two of them.

If you use

```
export variable=value other_value
```

without quoting the complete string `value other_value`, then `other_value` must be a valid name of a variable that you want to export.

In your case, use

```
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

rather than

```
export EDITOR=subl -w
```

if you want the `EDITOR` variable to have the value `subl -w`.

---

[In comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493360/zshrcexport97-not-valid-in-this-context-w-not-sure-what-this-means#comment906264_493360), you ask whether the duplication of the lines is necessary. No, the duplication is not necessary.

For the `export EDITOR` line, the duplicated line is a no-op (it just re-does the assignment and the `export`).  For the `export PATH` line, the second time you run the same statement, you will add the path `$HOME/bin` *again* to the end of the value of `PATH`.  This will have no practical consequences, but may slow down finding executables by a few fractions of a second.

Comment: The simple quote didn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Felipe That's too bad, but probably because you have a slightly different issue.